# linux: virtual mic using gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, microphone, alsa, pulseaudio

I want to dump audio data from an audio file to sound server so that I can emulate microphone. How to do this in ubuntu? Gstreamer solution is preferred.

**Flow:Audio file -> Sound server src(where mic also dumps its data)**

Already tried :

https://superuser.com/a/332434 : No clue how to do this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553706/5457916 : file is played very fast, it gets distorted

Comment: for the second solution you posted, did you ensure that format=s16le rate=16000 channels=1 are set to the correct values?

Comment: yes, i have tried it already, now i am working at 8khz, can this be a problem